# Is it possible to include a thumbnail in an element type index view?

Tags: plugin-development, elementtype

I'm trying to emulate what Assets does, in which a thumbnail of the asset is shown along side the title of the asset. When I alter the _toString() method of the model, what I get is the URL instead of the image (the URL is being added to the data-label attribute of the containing div).

Is there a way to accomplish what I'm after?

[image: The Element Type's title is displayed, but no image]

Answer (score 1):

*(Hopefully it is okay for me to answer my own question)*

In the **ElementType** file, the **getSources** method needs to have the *hasThumbs* key set, as follows:

```
public function getSources($context = null)
{
    $sources = array(
        '*' => array(
            'label'    => Craft::t('All assets'),
            'hasThumbs' => true,
        )
    );
}
```

In your **Model** file you have to have a **getThumbUrl** method defined, as follows:

```
public function getThumbUrl()
{
    return $this->thumbnailUrl;
}
```

This results in a small thumbnail next to the title of your element, as seen in the screenshot:

[image]

[The Craft 2 Class Reference](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v2/elementtypes/BaseElementType.html) helped put this together for me.